# Getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null with <script> at the end

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've looked at previous questions like this and cannot find the answer to my problem. I am working in javascript creating a checkout screen and I have two onclicks for two different html files but when I go to the html file for both it says that the other onclick is null. I have tried window.load and moving the script to the bottom of the

```
    var cart = [];
    var search = document.getElementById("addItem");
    let placement = 0;
  
    var cartElement = document.getElementById("showCart");
    var cartTotal = document.getElementById("totalCart");


        search.onclick = function(e) {
            var userInput = document.getElementById("query").value;
            var cartHTML = "";
            e.preventDefault();
            placement = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
            if (menu[i][0].includes(userInput)) {
            cart.push(menu[i]);
            placement++;
            }
        }
            if (placement == 0) {
            alert("Menu option not included. Please try again.");
            }
        
            cart.forEach((item, Order) => {
                var cartItem = document.createElement("span");
                cartItem.textContent = item[0] + " (" + item[1] + ")";
                cartHTML += cartItem.outerHTML;
              });
              cartElement.innerHTML = cartHTML;
        }
```

```
window.onload = function() {
    var checkout = document.getElementById("addCartButton");
    checkout.onclick = function(event) {
        cart.forEach()
        var cartTotalHTML = "";
        event.preventDefault();
        cart.forEach(Item, Order => {
            var totalInCart = 0;
            var writeCart = document.createElement("span");
            totalInCart += Order[1];
    
        });
        writeCart.textContent =  cartTotal += item[1];
        cartTotalHTML = writeCart.outerHTML;
        cartTotal.innerHTML = cartTotalHTML;
        console.log(cartTotal);
    }
}
```

```
<h3>Search for items in the menu below to add to cart</h3>
<form id="searchMenu"> 
    <input type="search" id="query" name="q" placeholder="Search Menu..."></inpuut>
    <input type = "Submit" name= "search" id="addItem" ></input>
  </form>
  <h4>Your cart: </h4>
  <div class="Cart">
    <div id="showCart"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="Script.js"></script>
```

```
<h4>Cart</h4>
<button id='addCartButton' class="Cart">Add Cart</button>
<div class="ShowCart">
    <div id="totalCart"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="Script.js"></script>
```

Comment: What element is null?

Comment: Are you sure you are loading the correct script file for each page?  They are both referencing script.js.